# preventing a chunk run in rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am using `Rmarkdown` and  `Knitr` using Rstudio.

The following both print script and output to html.

````
```{r}
summary(cars)
```
````

However the following will only print the output, that is embedded plot.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

I have situation different than above, I want to present the script but should not run in html as this will take very long time (hours if not days) to run. So I just did was put comment sign.

````
```{r}
#summary(cars)
```
````

But I need a better way to do this - Is there any better way presenting script without running it.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

```
eval = FALSE
```

Checkout The R Markdown Cheat Sheet http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/08/01/the-r-markdown-cheat-sheet/

It summarizes the options for code chunks

Comment: An addition (which I needed) for future reference: to prevent **all** code chunks to be run rather than single ones, include an hidden (`include=FALSE`) chunk at the begin of the document with `knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = FALSE)`